# pan-tompkins algorithm

Tags: discrete-signals, array-signal-processing

The difference equation of the differentiator used in pan-tompkins algorithm is as follows : ( a five-point derivative)

$$ y \left( n T \right) = \frac{1}{8} T \left[-x \left(nT - 2 T \right) - 2x \left(nT - T \right)+ 2x \left(nT + T \right) + x \left(nT + 2T \right) \right]$$

Can someone explain to me from where they got it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a "generic" *Finite Difference* (FD) five-point approximation to the first order derivative. You can find more information about the generic formulation of the FD derivative approximations in [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FDnotes.djvu) link (see the attached article)

The general approach is to expand function in its Taylor series around the $nT$ point. You expand as many times as you want to get the sought amount of points. The points of evaluation will be your $\left( nT - iT \right)$ points, where $i$ is an index that shows "how far" from the point of expansion you are evaluating (for example $i = 2$ gives the last point in your formula, $i = -2$ gives the first and $i = -1$ the second. I hope you see the pattern).

As a last step you have to find a linear combination of all the truncated Taylor series corresponding to each evaluation point. This ends up being a system of equations that has to be solved which can be done with linear algebra tools, or you could of course try to solve the equations in any other way.

---

### UPDATE

I have found some more time to provide more information. Please note that the presented derivation is a mix of information found on many sources, presented at the end of this answer.

I will change the argument of the function from $\left( nT + iT \right)$ to $\left(n + h \right)$ for the sake of simplicity. Where $h$ is the step in the free variable, equal to $h = T$ and here is considered to be constant and $n$ is the index of the sample. So if the central sample is $n$ then the previous is $n - h$ and the next $n + h$ and so on.

Denoting the derivative of a function $x$ with respect to $t$ as $x_{t}$, its second derivative with respect to $t$ as $x_{tt}$ and so on and assuming that these derivatives exist we have to show that the sought result is

$$ x' \left( n \right) = \frac{-x \left(n + 2h\right) + 8 x \left(n + h \right) - 8 x \left(n - h \right) + x \left(n - 2h\right)}{12 h} \label{1} \tag{1}$$

where $x'$ denotes the first derivative of $x$ with respect to the free variable. So, we calculate the (truncated) Taylor series for the points $\left\{ n - 2h, n - h, n + h, n + 2h \right\}$.

$$x \left(n + h \right) = x \left( n \right) + h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{h^{2}}{2} x'' \left( n \right) + \frac{h^{3}}{6} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{1+} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{2} \tag{2} $$

$$x \left(n - h \right) = x \left( n \right) - h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{h^{2}}{2} x'' \left( n \right) - \frac{h^{3}}{6} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{1-} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{3} \tag{3}$$

$$x \left(n + 2h \right) = x \left( n \right) + 2h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{4h^{2}}{2} x'' \left( n \right) + \frac{8 h^{3}}{6} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{2+} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{4} \tag{4} $$

$$x \left(n - 2h \right) = x \left( n \right) - 2h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{4h^{2}}{2} x'' \left( n \right) - \frac{8 h^{3}}{6} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{2-} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{5} \tag{5} $$

Now, evaluating $x \left( n + h \right) - x \left( n - h \right)$ we get

$$ x \left( n + h \right) - x \left( n - h \right) = 2 h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{ h^{3} }{3} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{1} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{6} \tag{6}$$

Similarly, $x \left( n + 2h \right) - x \left( n - 2h \right)$ is

$$ x \left( n + 2h \right) - x \left( n - 2h \right) = 4 h x' \left( n \right) + \frac{ 8 h^{3} }{3} x''' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O}_{2} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{7} \tag{7}$$

Note that $\mathcal{O}_{i}$ refers to the error corresponding to the points $i$ steps away from the central point.

Now, in order to eliminate the terms of $x''' \left( n \right)$ in \eqref{7} we multiply equation \eqref{6} with $8$ and plug it into \eqref{7} to get

$$ 8 x \left( n + h \right) - 8 x \left( n - h \right) - x \left( n + 2h \right) + x \left( n - 2h \right) = 12 h x' \left( n \right) + \mathcal{O} \left( h^{4} \right) \label{9} \tag{9}$$

which when solved for $x' \left( n \right)$ results in equation \eqref{1} which is the solution sought for.

There is a discrepancy with the multiplying factors between this solution and the formula you provided which I am not sure why this is the case. Since I am not familiar with the Pan-Tompkins algorithm and its use I cannot provide more help here. I hope someone else more knowledgeable in the field will be able to shed some more light.

### References and further reading

- Five points stencil wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-point_stencil
- MIT Finite-Difference derivative approximations text: https://web.mit.edu/16.90/BackUp/www/pdfs/Chapter12.pdf
- Derivative approximation text: https://geometrictools.com/Documentation/FiniteDifferences.pdf